# Generalize the idea of $A^2 = I_2$ to find a $5 \times 5$ matrix such that $M^2 = 0$ and $C$ is a nonzero $2 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

[image]

---

I know how to solve part (a) and (b), but I'm having trouble understanding question (c). In part (a) the A matrix is $2 \times 2$ but in question (c) it is $3 \times 3$ to satisfy the $M$ matrix dimension.  Can anybody explain how I can approach (c)?

Answer (score 0):

We must have $A \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R}), C \in M_{2 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and $D \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$. You have

$$ M^2 = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A^2 & 0 \\ CA + DC & D^2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

I'm not sure what the author means by the hint, but if you take $A = D = 0$ and $C$ any non-zero matrix, you will have $M^2 = 0$.

Comment: The authors comment is suggestion that, as in part (a), a non-zero entry in the bottom right can be canceled by the remaining entries. In other words, they're gesturing towards the idea that a matrix with the potential to become zero after enough multiplication (nilpotent) can be non-zero when it is strictly lower diagonal; a similar idea is arising from the first example for idempotent matrices.

Comment: I tried and I came up with one example which was A (dimension) has a value of 1 in the 1st row, 2nd column entry. Matrix C(2x3 dimension) has all zero entries except the 2nd row, 3rd column entry with a value of 2. D (dimension 2x2) has a value of 1 on the lower left entry and the rest of the entries are zero. The 0 matrix (dimension 3x2) on the top right of matrix M is has zeroes for all entries. With that my M matrix satisfies M^2 = 0. Just wondering if there's a way to generalize for M that satisfies the condition, M^2 = 0.